# Adjust Zoom Window Height Elevate Zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zooming

I use elevatezoom plugin in my app. What I want to do is just change zoomwindow height according to image hovering over. I could find a way but it does not work efficiently. It does not work when the page is first loaded. If I go to another page and see another product then elevatezoom is working as i want.

Here is my code with laravel url assignments:

```
<div class="product-main-image">
    <img src="{{URL::to($product->image)}}" alt="{{$product->title($product->id)}}" class="zoomInner img-responsive" data-zoom-image="{{URL::to($product->image)}}">
</div>
<div class="product-other-images" id="gallery_01">
    <a data-update="" data-image="{{URL::to($product->image)}}" data-zoom-image="{{URL::to($product->image)}}">
    <img alt="{{$product->title($product->id)}}" src="{{URL::to($product->image)}}"></a>
    @if(isset($images) && $images)
    @foreach($images as $image)
    <a  data-update="" data-image="{{URL::to($image->image)}}" data-zoom-image="{{URL::to($image->image)}}">
    <img alt="{{$product->title($product->id)}}" src="{{URL::to($image->image)}}"></a>
    @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

And here is thejavascript which initiates zoom and changes zoomwindow height:

```
    (function() {
      $(".product-main-image img").on("load",function() {
       var mainImgHeight=$(this).height();
       /*var src=$(this).attr("src");
        alert(src);*/
        $('.zoomInner').elevateZoom({
            gallery:'gallery_01',
            zoomType: "window",
            cursor: "crosshair",
            zoomWindowWidth:"400",
            zoomWindowHeight:mainImgHeight,
            zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
            zoomWindowFadeOut: 750
            });
        $(".product-main-image img").data("zoom-image","false").elevateZoom();
    });
```

})();

If I remove last row code snippet, zoom is working on first load However data-zoom-image does not change when product other images are clicked. How can I handle the problem. I think when i assign a global value ot "mainImgHeight" in load() function problem might be solved. But i could not get it work after one day hassle. Maybe someone has a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. It is simple solution. you can see the code and the descriptions below.

```
var firstImgHeight = $(".product-main-image img").height();
  $(".zoomWindow").css({"height":firstImgHeight});//assign height of first image to the zoomWindow height
        $('.zoomInner').elevateZoom({ //initiate zoom
            gallery:'gallery_01',
            zoomType: "window",
            cursor: "crosshair",
            zoomWindowWidth:"400",
            zoomWindowHeight:firstImgHeight,
            zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
            zoomWindowFadeOut: 750
            });
        $(".product-main-image img").on("load",function() { //change zoomWindow height when each image is loaded  (these images are big sizes of small thumnail images)
          var mainImgHeight=$(this).height();               // they are loaded by elevatezoom plugin 
          $(".zoomWindow").css({"height":mainImgHeight});
           var zoomWH = $(".zoomWindow").height();

       });
```

that solution works fine for me.